# iOS 11 Ionic slide-box transition bug.

Tags: ionic-framework, ios11, ion-slide-box, ionic-v1

I'm working on a Ionic 1 app. I have a slide box with multiple pictures. 
    Auto play is on so normally one picture leaves and another seamlessly 
    slides into its place. come the 4th transition and one picture slides 
    off but the next one does not follow. only white is left in its place. 
    once the initial slide has completely moved off screen the next slide then pops into view in the correct position without the nice transition.

extra info: when you manually swipe the slides they transition properly. bug only produced when slides are automatically transitioned.

eg code for slide-box

```
<ion-slide-box does-continue="true" slide-interval="5000" show-
pager="false" on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" auto-play="true" 
class="fly">
    <ion-slide>
      <a ui-sref="tab.flights">
        <img src="img/slides/Fly/fly1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </ion-slide>
```

[image: before transition]

[image: during transition]

[image: finished transition]

[image: after transition]